# Can jasmine rice and basmati rice be cooked together?

Tags: rice, mixing

I only have one cup of jasmine rice left, but plenty of basmati. Can I just mix them together in the rice cooker?

Comment: Not sure in the rice cooker but I just mixed 1 cup of Jasmine with 1 cup of wild rice in a pot and it tasted great. :)

Comment: Well I ended up doing it (1 cup of each), and it was fantastic! :-)

Comment: Glad it worked out :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It shouldn't be a problem, since their cooking times are similar.

Answer (score 1):

Since their cooking times are similar, I'm sure it would be no problem to mix them.

In my experience - maybe it depends on the rice cooker? - it's possible to cook two very different types of rice at once in a rice cooker.

For example, I've had no problems mixing brown and white rice in my rice cooker.  I wash them separately, put brown rice on one side of the pot, white on the other, and then add water slowly so they don't get mixed around much.  I put in as much water as I would if it were all brown rice and then cook as normally.  The white rice comes out a little bit on the sticky side, but not to the point that it seems like gruel, and the brown rice is just right.